# CSS: div different position in mobile view

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

My desktop webpage has the following design:

```
---------------------
|elem1|elem2|tabs   |
|     |     |-------|
|     |     |t1 | t2|
|     |     |       |
---------------------
```

Tabs is a container provided by Bootstrap (http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs); t1 and t2 are some tabs inside that container.

Now I want to create a responsive design, so if the user switches to the mobile view the website should look the following (portrait mode):

```
-------------
|elem2      |
|-----------|
|tabs       |
|-----------|
|elem1|t1|t2|
-------------
```

So basically I want that elem1 (left in the desktop) moves into my tab container and becomes a tab itself (or at least the content of a tab that is only visible in the mobile view). Is this even possible with a CSS-**only** solution?

First I thought about putting creating the elem1 twice and display the correct one depending on the screen size but I don't like that solution due to maintenance.

Comment: Are you sure that `elem1` and `tabs` are in correct position in second view?

Comment: @AliSheikhpour Yes I want to place elem1 inside my tabs container. So it should become a tab by itself (or at least the content of a tab that is only visible in the mobile view)

Comment: You can accomplish this with using heights as long as bootstrap uses floating but It will surely cause problems in future because as It turns out in first view you have bold rules like elem1, elem2 and tabs are for sure divides the view into 3 sections and you would like tabs (t1, t2) under tabs section no matter how your tabs grow. Long story short If you may do it with floating units and giving a large height on elem1 and elem2 and depending on viewport you decrease the height and use bootstrap's pull tags.

Comment: Also you may use jQuery to do this task easily. Detect viewport and change the element's position in document /w out breaking the design rules. I would go for jQuery if I were you. Because this can be achieved by using css but it will surely break your design rules in first demonstration

Comment: @EmirhanÖzlen yeah I think with jQuery it will be easy. But I'm interested if this is even possible with css only.

Comment: @Philipp It is possible If you agree the design that your all html elements are floating in first demonstration but they are not. This problem goes beyond css. Involves changing the parent of html elements. As you can see in the first demonstration, elem1 is a child of body. In the second demonstration It is a child of tabs element. UNLESS you accept that all those elements are children of body and they are floating then you can for sure use css to position them in right order. But as I told you It will surely cause so many problems in future.

Comment: @EmirhanÖzlen ok then I will go with jQuery. thx for your advice

Comment: @Philipp No problems, I'd like to hear what others think tho.